# Can anyone explain how list = [[] for _ in range(vertex)] works?

Tags: python

Looks like it prints out something like [[], [], []].

could someone rephrase it without using list comprehension?

Comment: What is vertex? Can you post the complete code?

Comment: assuming `vertex` is an integer, this just loops `vertex` times, adding an empty list to a list. You will end up with a list of `n` empty lists, where `n=vertex`

Comment: is_weighted = False
    is_directed = False
    graph_list = graph_str.splitlines()
    num_verticies = int(graph_list[0].split()[1])
    graph_list.pop(0)
    adj_list = [[] for _ in range(num_verticies)]
    print(adj_list)

Comment: how do i format code 
:/

Comment: Thanks  Zinki is it possible to do it without using list comprehension?

Comment: Update your question, do not put the code in the comment

Comment: I have edited your question.. you need to indent with 4 spaces to grey the code

Comment: I have provided an answer without list complrehension..

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a list of empty lists of size **vertex**.
These are called list comprehensions.

For ex:

```
foo = [i for i in range(10)]
print(foo)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Read more https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.

Also, post complete code next time for others to comprehend and help you.

Comment: It seems that you working with graphs (and probably trying to make an adjacency list). Here's a simple code: https://ideone.com/Ij0OUD

Comment: This was very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without list comprehension it would simply be

```
is_weighted = False 
is_directed = False 
graph_list = graph_str.splitlines() 
num_verticies = int(graph_list[0].split()[1]) 
graph_list.pop(0)

adj_list = [] #create an empty list to append to

for x in range(num_verticies): #start the for loop
    adj_list.append([]) #append an empty list the num_vertices times

print(adj_list)
```